# Issue with spring cloud config property file order

Tags: spring-cloud

I am using spring cloud config for loading properties file for my application. I have multiple environments. I notice that the property files are loaded in wrong order. This is what i see in my logs

> Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource [name='https://github.com/xyz/configrepo.git/gatekeeper-dev.properties'], MapPropertySource [name='https://github.com/xyz/configrepo.git/gatekeeper.properties']]]

It seems that the environment specific property file is loaded first and overridden by the default property file. Is there any way i can control the order in which they are loaded and processed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected order (for good reasons so I am surprised you found a use case where it wasn't convenient). You can't control it except by changing the names of the files and listing them in a comma separated form. For the sake of clarity: profile specific properties always override default ones. Possibly the logs have confused you.

Comment: Hey @dsyer - The way i see it is that you have a base property file and then environment specific overrides. Can you explain a bit how the other way round makes more sense ? I am obviously missing the point. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: The order as implemented is as you say (environment specific properties override the defaults). I guess you just misinterpreted the log output?